# C# CopyFromScreen filling up memory

Tags: c#, .net, memory, screenshot

I am using this code to take screen shot every second with timer, but it seems to be filling up my memory (about 30 MB each take)... This is the code:

```
Bitmap bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
Graphics gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);
gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(136, 93, 9, 0, new Size(1088-391, 1039-65), CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

return bmpScreenshot;
```

Is there a way to clear memory?

Comment: You need to `Dispose()` things.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dispose of things properly by calling `Dispose` or wrapping with the `using()` statement which calls it for you, for example:

```
Bitmap bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

using(Graphics gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot)) {
    gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(136, 93, 9, 0, new Size(1088-391, 1039-65),   CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
}

return bmpScreenshot;
```

You should also dispose of the returned `Bitmap` instance once you're done with it.

Comment: @user1176999 can you elaborate? what error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem, too.

```
var g = CreateGraphics();

using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red))
{
    Point point = new Point(0,0);
    Rectangle sourceRect = new Rectangle(100,100,100,100);

    var invoker = new MethodInvoker(() =>
    {
        // The following line will filling up the memory.
        g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(0,0), sourceRect.Location, sourceRect.Size);
    });
    do
    {
        BeginInvoke(invoker);
    } while (!mre.WaitOne(1));
}
```

It means the 'CopyFromScreen' method has some things that are not disposed.
But I have no idea how to dispose them.
Even through 'Diagnositics Tools' of VS2017, I can see the heap usage and point to ExecutionContext -> Queue, the Queue is going larger and larger, and mostly, the size of each item in the Queue is 44 bytes. Of cause, GC will collect them after a while, but it still grow up quickly.

Answer (score 0):

`Bitmap` and `Graphics` implement IDisposable interface. To free unmanaged resources you should call `Dispose` method or wrap both objects with `using` statement.

Comment: @codemann8, wtf? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry, it appears it does per the documentation, however, when I added a using() around a Bitmap, it threw an error saying it didn't implement IDisposable so now I'm confused...I removed my earlier comment